# What points is the norm Frechet differentiable at

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

[image]

I know the definition of Frechet derivatives - there exists a bounded linear map...
Maybe someone could show me a similar example on how to approach questions like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a) we know if all partial derivatives exist at $x$ then $f$ is Frechet differentiable at $x$ since $\mathbb{R^n}$ is finite.
Now consider the partial derivative in the direction $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+he_i)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|x_i+h|-|x_i|}{h} $$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th Euclidean basis vector.
Now when $x_i=0$ this limit does not exist as we see the left limit does not equal the right limit (otherwise the limit is the same from both sides). Hence the 1-norm is only Frechet differentiable at $\{x\in \mathbb{R^n} | x_i \neq0\, \forall 1\leq i \leq n\}$
See if you can do something similar for b)

Comment: On the top line of the first limit, f here is the 1-norm which is the sum. However we see that we have 2 sums where every term cancels except $|x_i+h|$ in the first and $-|x_i|$ in the second. Do you understand now?

Comment: $f(x+he_i)-f(x)=||(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},x_i+h,x_{i+1},\dots,x_n)||-||(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n)||=|x_i+h|-|x_i|$

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking but basically try to find points at which the left limit does not equal the right limit of the partial derivative

Answer (score 2):

For (a): all points outside the hyperplanes $x_i=0$.

For (b): all points outside the hyperplanes $x_i=\pm x_j$ with $i\ne j$.

How to approach the problem: consider first $n=2$ and the function $|x|+|y|$ and $\max\{|x|,|y|\}$.

Added: Let me detail all for $n=2$. Outside the regions that I mentioned, the functions is differentiable:

For (a) it is either $x+y$, $x-y$, $-x-y$ or $-x+y$, all of them differentiable.

For (b) it is either $x$, $-x$, $y$ or $-y$, all of them differentiable.

On the other points (to check that the functions are not differentiable) it is sufficient to verify that the functions are not differentiable along at least one direction. For example, for (a) and the points $(0,y)$ note that the function $(0,y)\mapsto|0|+|y|=|y|$ is not differentiable (compute the derivative along the direction $(0,1)$).

Comment: How did you achieve the answers from the definition?

Comment: First think about $n=2$, the rest is analogous. As always one should suspect that the problem comes from zero when considering $|x|$.

Comment: So for (a): $\lim_{v \rightarrow 0} \frac{||\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ |v_i|-Av\ ||}{||v||}$ What is A? How do I continue?

Comment: Don't think like that. For example: $|x|+|y|=x+y$ for $x,y>0$ and $|x|+|y|=x-y$ for $x>0,y<0$. So, for $x>0$ when you pass through $y=0$ there is no derivative with respect to $y$. Etc.

Comment: What definition is used for Frechet derivatives then? I am confused. I understand the bounded linear map definition for functions. But what about norms?

Comment: The definition is the one above, sure, but sometimes mathematics is really not about making automatic computations. This is one of those cases (if you prefer, we can just say that in this case what is important is to find the points where there is no derivative and for that it is impossible to use your limit since it is not defined at those points). Please read my former comment carefully, and try to make a generalization.

Comment: $|x_1|+|x_2|+\ldots+|x_i|+\ldots+|x_n| = x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_i+\ldots+x_n$ for ... and $|x_1|+|x_2|+\ldots+|x_i|+\ldots+|x_n| = x_1+x_2+\ldots-x_i+\ldots+x_n$ for ... Is this correct? Will change into summation after

Comment: How do I show the others points are differentiable then? And isn't this for differentiability, what about Frechet?

Comment: Intuitively I now see why they aren't differentiable at the points you have mentioned. But I still need to show they are differentiable at the other points.

Comment: Just added details to my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: For (b) what would be the for? For (a) it was $>0$ and $<0$.

Comment: And could you please show me how to write out the limit with (a)

Comment: There is no limit to write, you only need to look at the functions, they are clearly differentiable. But if you want to write it is simply the usual derivative.

Comment: I mean for not Frechet differentiable at 0.

Comment: The same comment applies (as for differentiable). Sorry to say that you complicate too much, it is much more important to understand the idea, and if you do, you see that there is nothing more to write.

Answer (score 0):

**Ad (a):** Let $f(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$, and consider a point $a\in{\mathbb R}^n$ with $a_i\ne0$ for all $i\in[n]$. Then   $$U:=\bigl\{x\>\bigm|\>|x_i-a_i|<|a_i| \ (i\in[n])\bigr\}$$ is an open box with center $a$ and
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n {\rm sgn}(a_i)\>x_i\qquad(x\in U)\ .$$
This shows that $f$ is linear in $U$, hence Fréchet differentiable at $a$.

On the other hand, if one $a_r=0$ then the function $\phi(t):=f(a+ te_r)$ is equal to $f(a)+|t|$ for small $|t|$, hence is not differentiable at $t=0$, and this is incompatible with $f$ being Fréchet differentiable  at $a$.

**Ad (b):** Let $g(x):=\max_{1\leq i\leq n} |x_i|$, and consider a point $a\in{\mathbb R}^n$ with 
$$|a_r|=\max_{i\in[n]}|a_i|>\max_{i\in[n]\setminus\{r\}}|a_i|=:p\ ,$$
i.e., a point $a$ with a uniquely determined maximal $|a_i|$. Put $\delta:={1\over2}\bigl(|a_r|-p\bigr)$. Then   $$U:=\bigl\{x\>\bigm|\>|x_i-a_i|<\delta\ (i\in[n])\bigr\}$$ is an open box with center $a$ and
$$g(x)=x_r\qquad(x\in U)\ .$$
This shows that $g$ is linear in $U$, hence Fréchet differentiable at $a$.

On the other hand, if there are $r\ne s$ with
$$|a_r|=|a_s|=\max_{i\in[n]}|a_i|>\max_{i\in[n]\setminus\{r,s\}}|a_i|\ ,$$
then for a suitable choice of signs the function $$\phi(t):=g\bigl(a\pm te_r\pm t e_s)$$ is equal to $g(a)+|t|$ for small $|t|$, hence  is not differentiable at $t=0$, and this is incompatible with $g$ being Fréchet differentiable  at $a$.